# NET USE with escape characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use `NET USE` to create a connection with a virtual machine.

When I try to put the password parameter, it tells me that there was a syntax error.

This is my code:

```
set ip=123.45.67.89
set username=teste
set password="/Iyv*4gUoD[PUWLrn2/j"

NET USE K: \\%ip%\c$ /user:"DIR\%username%" %password%
```

And the error is this:

```
NET USE K: \\%ip%\c$ /user:"DIR\%username%" %password%
The option /IYV*4GUOD[PUWLRN2/J is unknown.

The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [/REQUIREINTEGRITY]
        [/REQUIREPRIVACY]
        [/WRITETHROUGH]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3506.
```

I know there's something wrong with escape characters in my password string but I can't find a way to solve it.

Comment: Despite the usage information not showing it, the safest, _and therefore recommended_, way to define a variable using `set`, is `SET "VARNAME=VALUESTRING"`. I would suggest therefore, that `set "ip=123.45.67.89"`, `set "username=teste"`, `set "password=/Iyv*4gUoD[PUWLrn2/j"`, and `NET USE K: "\\%ip%\c$" /user:"DIR\%username%" "%password%"` would seem more like that syntax.

Comment: I suppose, the problem is, that your password begins with a slash `/`, this indicates for `NET` that you want to add an option. This is simply a problem of a weak implementation of the `NET` program. Perhaps you can redirect your password to `echo /IYV*4GUOD[PUWLRN2/J | NET USE ...` ... or change your password to `123456`

Comment: You want me to write like this?

echo /Iyv*4gUoD[PUWLrn2/j | NET USE K: \\%ip%\c$ /user:"DIR\%username%" %password%

Comment: @AlexandreCristo Yes, you could try, but it could fail, because there is a trailing space inserted by the pipe processing

Comment: It doesn't work either! Something in NET USE is changing my password to capital letters!

Comment: I would also ask, given the usage information you've yourself seen and posted, what `DIR` is supposed to represent? _because it doesn't really look like a `domainname`, or a `dotted domain name` either_. I would also advise that you change the name of the variable `username`, to something which doesn't overwrite a built-in ststem environment variable name.

Comment: It's a domain name

Comment: `echo /Iyv*4gUoD[PUWLrn2/j | NET USE K: \\%ip%\c$ /user:"DIR\%username%" *` The star tells the `net use` command to get the password from stdin, which you are doing by `echo`'ing to the pipe.

Comment: @AlexandreCristo, you should write that up as the answer.